# Unable to create shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am very new to QGIS and although I've been able to download the software and get aerial imagery using the plugins menu, I'm getting nowhere with creating a shapefile that I can use to draw a polygon on the aerial image. I've gone through the layer - create new shapefile procedure many times, but when prompted to save the shapefile on my C:drive, nothing happens.  I've tried using "add vector layer" then searching for the file I thought I'd saved, but there is nothing there.  Nor does the shapefile appear on the layers menu on the left of the project.  Where am I going wrong please?

Comment: Thanks Andre - saving elsewhere seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have full write permissions on C:\ ? Try alternatively your user directory.

A Windows- user name or folder name with non-ASCII-characters may spoil the saving as well.